# electrical wiring in panel for heater

Tags: wiring, heater

what type of wiring and circuit breaker for outdoor patio heater 4000 watts, 240 v. 16.6 amp.  Could i use standard 12 ga wire and 20 amp circuit breaker?

Comment: Will this be plug in or hard wired?

Comment: What do the instructions specify ?  Straight following Code you need #10/30A, but if UL approved instructions allowing #12/20A then you get lucky.

Comment: I would verify that the resistance is 14.5 ohms by nameplate 4000/240 is 16.6 amps and that is 20.8A when increased to 125%..  is this a UL listed heater? Normally if they are bumping the limit they jump to 5000w because by code they both require a 30 amp circuit. I have seen devices that state a 20 amp circuit but it would have to be UL listed in the US. I know on the Oregon “masters test” they go 1 or 2 tenths over to make sure you go up to the next size and those questions are in the 500 amp range.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's acceptable.  The 12 ga. wire is good for 20A and that coupled with a 20A breaker will give you what you need.

Comment: No, you need to derate heaters at 125%.

Comment: 125% of 16A is 20A.  I suppose that pesky 0.75A from 16.6A will force 10g wire?  I wouldn't do it for that but what do I know?

Comment: Manufacturers are well aware of those derating rules, and generally size their units accordingly.  One that made such an awkward size of heater is likely to have addressed the issue with UL; a solution will be addressed in the instructions.

Comment: While I don't like to "push the limits" the NEC does have a lot of safety margins built in and I think you'd be fine, so I agree with @jwh20, the excess over the derating is only .75 amps. That said, how long is the run between the patio heater and the power source (presumably the main panel)?  You should consider voltage drop if a long run and small difference in cost if the run is short.   If it was my home, I'd run 10 gauge to address the safety and voltage drop issues. The cost diff between a 20 amp and 30 amp breaker is nominal if anything.   Take care and wire on!